# What is the significance of Katana Swords being the weapon for Deadpool?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool

I was watching *[Deadpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool_(film))* and one thing which stuck in my mind is why katana swords. Nowhere in the movie is Wade Wilson shown as a master of operating swords.

Then what was the reason that Deadpool chose a katana sword as a weapon?

Comment: "Nowhere in the movie is Wade Wilson shown as a master of operating swords." Uhh, did we watch the same movie? He looked plenty competent to me.

Comment: in the movie however, deadpool was not shown learning to use Guns and altheletic jumping....but he does it well. i guess that has been kept as an understanding for us by movie makers. :)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist:Did you understand the difference between Wade WIlson and Deadpool if yes then only i guess you could understand the Question.

Comment: Wade wilson: Before being the Deadpool

Comment: Katanas were traditionally the sword associated with the Samurai class of Japan rather than ninjas.

Comment: Because katanas are cool.  Not sure if it goes beyond that.

Comment: Katanas don't run out of ammo.

Comment: @JDoe Neither do claymores. (The sword kind, not the mine kind.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deadpool uses ninja swords, katanas, because he uses katanas in the comics. It's *adaptation tautology*. He has had katanas since his first introduction in 1991. He actually mastered kenjutsu and how to use katanas the normal way. He was even a sumo wrestler for a while (not in a joke manner).

In the movie universe, it's because they look cool. Wade is all about looking cool. It's not supposed to be a deep reason.

Answer (score 5):

From [this](http://www.superherodb.com/deadpool/10-835/equipment/)

> Deadpool employs any number of weapons depending on his current assignment. Most often, Deadpool uses guns, grenades, sais, knives, and katanas. **Wade can use any weapon known to man and learn how to use the weapon in less than 5 minutes.**

and from [this](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool%27s_Katanas)

> Although Wilson also uses guns from time to time, he seems to prefer taking out his swords as they've proven to be more lethal than any firearm

Comment: Um, that doesn't seem to explain anything at all, apart from simply restating what the movie and this question already say. Yeah, he likes ninja swords, obviously.

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson I think the first part of the answer explains how he can use it skillfully despite "Nowhere in the movie is shown as a master of operating swords" and the second part explains the why, "they've proven to be more lethal than any firearm" which is "the reason that Deadpool chose a ninja sword as a weapon"

Comment: @NapoleonWilson The question seems to be based on a faulty premise (or is very poorly worded). The Deadpool that *I* saw was definitely more than competent with swords, at least to dispatch nameless mercenaries and to go up against Francis. Saying "Nowhere in the movie is Wade Wilson shown as a master of operating swords." is simply untrue, in my opinion.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sure, that might actually make for a reasonable answer on its own then.

Comment: @Anthony Grist   OP means Wade Wilson not Deadpool. "Wade didn't show any signs that he can use swords before and now after he gained his superpowers, swords became his weapon of choice all of the sudden?"

Comment: @madmada In the movie he's forced into using his swords because he forgets his guns and/or ammo, the plan definitely wasn't to confront Ajax/Francis with them, the plan was to blow him away with an unnecessarily large amount of firepower. Besides, just because he's not shown using swords before mutating doesn't mean he *couldn't* use them.

Comment: @Anthony Grist I'm not really disagreeing with you about anything, just pointing out that the question (as I understood it) about Wade not shown as a sword master and deadpool is and what's the reason behind that

Answer (score 0):

Purely in the movie, Wade is said to both be former special forces and a mercenary, making a good case that he learned close quarters combat techniques in the military. I don't think it's too far of a stretch to assume he used swords as a mercenary beforehand based on previous versions of the character (such as the referenced *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*) and his apparent experience with them. Or, if we asked Deadpool, he'd probably say he copied Deathstroke.

Answer (score 0):

The Katana Swords are usually the best for the job and he does use similar weapons in the movie. He uses sharp weapons which re useful and are the usual thought of how to kill other than uusing a gun. Deadpool's powers are why is easily so acrobatic automaticlly. His powers make him a better marksman, allowing him to make his shots in akward angles. Deadpool's abilities expand far beyond just being an increased healing factor and immortality. Funny ability includes increased metabolismwith his real favorite food being pancakes. Deadpool is an insanely powerful mutant. The swords are a weapon that is easy to use and suits his abilities.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously the movie hasn't told all of Deadpool's story (really, Wade's story for that matter), there's more material to pull from the comics. If you're sticking completely from the movies, his first appearance is NOT his solo movie.

Though may people disliked his story-line in the movie "Wolverine", he is shown there on a mission using the swords as well. This gives us evidence that he did indeed know how to use them before he became Deadpool, as well as suggesting they were his weapon of choice.

In the comics, Deadpool is a highly trained assassin and mercenary, and has studied multiple forms of martial arts. He is also a swordsman and marksman. At the end of the day, he uses swords because that's what the writers chose.

Comment: Different timeline, doesn't count. ...